# why does this javascript prime number code fail when i=9?

Tags: javascript

I have written this *javascript* prime number function but it says 9 is a prime and i can't find out what is wrong with 9.

```
function prime(...num) {
for (let i of range(...num)) {
    for (let j of range(2,i)) {
        if (i%j===0) {
        console.log(i+' is not a prime number' );
        break;
        }else{
         console.log(i + ' is a prime number');                          }
    break;    
    }
}
```

}

I expected the following output when i run `prime(range(8,10));`:

```
8 is not a prime number
9 is not a prime number
```

but it instead returns:

```
8 is not a prime number
9 is a prime number
```

Answer (score 0):

A good first step would be to remove the `break` statement form the end of your loop body. If you keep it, the loop will only run for one iteration!

Also, before printing `i is a prime number`, you need to ensure that `i%j` has been checked against all values of j between 2 and `i`. So you can add a condition to your `else` block to reflect that:

```
for (let i of range(...num)) {
    for (let j of range(2,i)) {
        if (i%j===0) {
            console.log(i+' is not a prime number' );
            break;
        }
        else if(j == i-1) { //we reached the last iteration
            console.log(i + ' is a prime number');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are only executing the first division (by 2), checking if the modulo is equal to 0 and if it is and basing your answer on that.

Here is some pseudocode that should help you:

```
notPrime = false
for (let j of range(2,i))
        if (i%j===0) 
            notPrime = true
            break    //it is not necessary if a divisor is found.

if (notPrime)
    console.log(i+' is not a prime number' );
else
    console.log(i + ' is a prime number');
```

There are many improvements to this algorithm, but the easiest one is to use `range(2, n/2)`. You'll find no divisors in the range `[n/2 + 1, n - 1]`.